# Are Structs in C++ allocated memory sequentially? Somehow getting correct answer for pointer comparison everytime

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to solve a problem.

**Problem definition:**  Given a singly linked list containing n nodes. Modify the value of first half nodes such that 1st node’s new value is equal to the last node’s value minus first node’s current value, 2nd node’s new value is equal to the second last node’s value minus 2nd node’s current value, likewise for first half nodes. If n is odd then the value of the middle node remains unchanged. Note that the half nodes of linked list remain unmodified.

EG :  6 3 5 4 10

ans: 
-4 -1 5 4 10

I wrote a program to keep track of nodes in the second half in reverse order needed for processing using recursion. But, out of carelessness, I compared **both the pointers** to check whether both the pointers have crossed each other to stop processing them.

I am getting the output, everytime correctly.

**FULL CODE**:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* modifyTheList(struct Node *head);
void push(struct Node **head_ref, int new_data)
{
  struct Node* new_node =(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  new_node->data = new_data;
  new_node->next = *head_ref;    
  *head_ref = new_node;
}
void printList(struct Node *head)
{
    if (!head)
        return;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << head->data << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        struct Node *head = NULL;
        while(n--){
            int a;
            cin>>a;
            push(&head, a);
        }
        head = modifyTheList(head);
        printList(head);
    }
    return 0;
}

void modify(Node *head ,Node** left)
{
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        modify(head->next,left);
        if(head >= *left )            //line of concern, comparing pointers
            return;
        else
        {
            (*left)->data=(*left)->data-head->data;
            (*left)=(*left)->next;
        }
    }
}
struct Node* modifyTheList(struct Node *head)
{
    if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL )
        return head;
    struct Node *temp = head;
    modify(head,&temp);
    return head;
}
```

1. Can someone tell me is it valid to compare this way?
2. If this is not valid, how it passed the test cases of an online judge?

Comment: No, it is _absolutely not_ guaranteed that each successively `malloc()`d object has a later address than all previous ones; you just got 'lucky'. You can't rely on that. Otherwise, think about it: the library would be one huge memory leak, unable to reclaim memory from deallocated objects, as it would not be allowed to go back to lower addresses to allocate new ones... Also, `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` What is this meant to achieve? You're not meant to include fragments of standard libraries like that.

Comment: `If this is not valid, how it passed the test cases of an online judge?` I don't know why this is confusing. Sometimes things work how your first intuition expects, even if they are not required to.

Comment: Such pointer comparison is *undefined behaviour*. You are only allowed to compare pointers that point into the same array. `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard C++, don't use it.

Comment: @n.m. Then how are iterators implemented? You can compare iterator of list to the end iterator. Is there some magic underneath?

Comment: @zoska - List iterators are not plain pointers, and may be implemented with any number of techniques that involve more meta-data about the list.

Comment: @zoska you can always compare pointers with `==` and `!=`, I'm talking about `<` `>` and friends. (Iterators don't have to be pointers).

Comment: @StoryTeller I get it, but stl implements iterators as pointers. n.m. clarified which operators are illegal

Comment: @zoska - Your first sentence is either a misrepresentation of something you read, or your were lied to. Only `std::vector::iterator` is ever a plain pointer, and usually only in optimized code.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've especially checked std::list::iterators implementation, before I expressed my doubts about pointers comparison. Maybe I didn't dig to it enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me is it valid to compare this way?

You can't directly compare pointers unless they point to subobjects of the same array, or members of the same object. Formally, objects that are not part of the same array are considered part of *separate* 1-element arrays. There is no defined result for comparing their pointers. To quote N4296:

**§5.9 Relational operators [expr.rel] ְְ¶3**

> Comparing pointers to objects<sup>86</sup> is defined as follows:
>   (3.1) — If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to
>   subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher
>   subscript compares greater.
>   (3.2) — If one pointer points to an
>   element of an array, or to a subobject thereof, and another pointer
>   points one past the last element of the array, the latter pointer
>   compares greater.
>   (3.3) — If two pointers point to different
>   non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such
>   members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member
>   compares greater provided the two members have the same access control
>   (Clause 11) and provided their class is not a union.
>
> ---
>
> 86) An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose; see 5.3.1.

So you can't compare directly, and your program is officially with undefined behavior. However, such comparison can be useful, which is why the standard gives you another way:

**§20.9.6 Comparisons [comparisons] ְְ¶14**

> For templates greater, less, greater_equal, and less_equal, the specializations for any pointer type
>   yield a total order, even if the built-in operators <, >, <=, >= do not.

So your code can be made well defined, by simply replacing `head >= *left` with a call to `std::greater_equal<Node*>(head, *left)`.

---

> If this is not valid, how it passed the test cases of an online judge?

Undefined behavior means any outcome is allowed by the language specification. "Working" is a possible outcome. You just can't rely on it to *always* be the outcome.

Comment: Hey! how does this make the code well defined? `std::greater_equal<Node*>(head, *left). `. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JinxerAlbatross - By the fact the standard describes it as well defined, as specified in the quoted paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is absolutely no guarantee about the relational position of memory from different allocations.

> If this is not valid, how it passed the test cases of an online judge?

The easy answer (from me) is to say you got (un)lucky. The truth is that the mechanism of memory allocation/mapping is complex and covers more layers: application (`malloc`), C library implementation, OS and hardware. It is possible and in some situations even probable that consecutive `malloc` requests return memory that is somewhat consecutive. This is in by no way a guarantee and can easily break (e.g. after a series of intertwined `malloc`s and `free`s).

Moreover, as @StoryTeller shows, comparing pointers (except equality) to different objects is UB.